# how to enforce TLS1.2 for tibjms client?

Tags: ssl, tibco, tibco-ems

I've got a question of how to enforce **TLSv1.2** in **tibjms 8.3** client? In **tibems 8.3** release note it said **TLSv1.2** is supported. But I don't know how to set it in **tibjms** client? (which I am using)

According to the **tibco** [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.1-march-2013/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/admin/RVCMTransportInfo.html) of  **TibjmsContext**, the **SECURITY_PROTOCOL** parameter could be only accepting "ssl"

So how is TLSv1.2 supported in tibco? Can we programmatically set it in client?

Comment: What java version is used? What is Tibco BW and EMS version on server side?

Answer (score 0):

1. TIBCO has confirmed the bug and has issued hotfix 010
   (tib_ems_8.3.0_hf_010), contact them for more details.
2. For Enabling TLS V1.2 in TIBCO BW 5.13, add the following in
   bwengine.tra file(available in the path TIBCO_HOME\bw\5.13\bin) :

> "java.property.TIBCO_SECURITY_VENDOR=j2se"